# What music plays at 16:23 of FMA Brotherhood episode 62?

Tags: music, fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

I can't find the track name. Its when Armstrong comes to the King Bradley's corpse and has a monologue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally got it, it's called **The Day the Sun Disappeared**. It's the 17th track from *Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood Original Soundtrack 3*.